# replacing CALayer arrays with CAMetalLayer arrays

Tags: arrays, uiimageview, calayer, metal

I have a painting app which at any given time interactively shows content from an array of 200 or so `CALayer`s via an `UIImageView`.  I get reasonable performance, but I'm wondering if there could be any performance benefits with using `CAMetalLayer`s instead. In particular, I'm curious if I could benefit from blitting textures directly to each `CAMetalLayer`, and would there be any hardware considerations with stacking/displaying so many `CAMetalLayer`s at once.

Are there any gotchas I should consider before implementing, and should I continue using an `UIImageView` (or other) to host these newly Metal-backed sublayers?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You are just asking for trouble with 200 layers. You are going to burn up all the app memory that way. Why would you try to implement a painting app this way? Are you attempting to support multiple steps of undo? A better approach is to use 1 layer that collects all the combined painting steps into 1 texture that can then be written into a metal drawable with a single operation.

Comment: Undo is exactly the reason.  Each CALayer just holds a brushstroke, and it does so efficiently since it just the size of the stroke's bounding box. Granted, 200 layers is an upper limit, but thus far with this implementation, memory consumption is kept in check.  Can you expand a little on your suggested approach?

Comment: The long and the short of it is, iOS is not going to be able to handle the memory usage in the approach you describe. If you are only running on Macs then you might be able to get away with more layers, but iOS will generate memory warnings and then your app will be killed due to memory usage. The right way to do this is to store the "brushstrokes" data as X,Y and metadata like stroke width and color and so on. Then, at any point you can "undo" by reconstructing the entire combined buffer from the metadata up to the point where the undo walks back.

Comment: My target is iOS, and, yes, I also think my current approach is not optimal.  I do have the brushstroke data you suggest available in the form of files on disk and/or, arrays of CGImage...Do you think that building an entire buffer from this data would be an efficient, performance-friendly way to go?  Doing so would mean that going from frame 200 to frame 199, I'd have MTKView rebuild the entire frame buffer from 199 stored strokes. Does this sound right?

Comment: You would need to store stroke data as vectored (X,Y, stroke color and so on) data, not pixel buffers. You then create the pixel buffers from the data and combine the pixels into one single buffer that contains the strokes in order. The point is that this means that many strokes can be stored in memory without holding pixel buffers. Holding the pixel buffers is what will consume all the app memory.

Comment: Here are some raw numbers on the kind of memory usage I am talking about, each "stroke" you would store as a pixel buffer is the same as a video frame: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post5_video_and_memory_usage_on_ios_devices/index.html

Comment: I will study the link you just sent, thank you.  Let me rephrase my earlier question.  I build each stroke interactively in Metal out of arrays of overlapping stamps--(You've been super helpful with my posts on this front, thank you). With this data, (which, might consist of several hundred polygons for one stroke, up to thousands for many strokes), you are suggesting I build my history on a single buffer whenever I want to scrub through my history, correct? If so, might not the large poly count become a bottleneck for interactivity?. I have decent performance with my current CALayer approach.

Comment: I am saying the root problem with your design is memory usage. The correct fix is to build up one "inprogress" texture that collects all the strokes as one pixel buffer. If the user kicks off an undo operation, then undo can be implemented by rebuilding the buffer. In the normal case, there is no undo and no memory or performance issue.

Comment: I am on the same page with you.  Just trying to clarify my way forward.  I see the advantage of building everything as an "in progress" texture.  I'm just trying to think through the implementation of, say going from a view that has built up 200 strokes, backwards in time to when there were just, say 10.  Or vice versa, going forwards in time from stroke 10, to stroke 200th. (I can do this in my current implementation)  In these scenarios, the entire "in progress" texture would be rebuilt. This scrubbing through history feature is one that I want to keep, but build it smartly.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not going to work. You should be keeping track of your stroke’s data. For example an array of points would be a single stroke and then you should have an array of those strokes. It could be only points (x, y) or more probably also containing color, size and other variables. You should know what do you need to describe your stroke.

Then use that to draw (stamp at those locations). When you want to undo, just start drawing from the beginning all the strokes in the array until n-1, n-2, etc...

Comment: I do have all that data, and I can probably implement as suggested.  I worry about the impact of scrubbing backwards and forwards through my history (arbitrarily through a history slider, as I have now)...In other words, I'd be pushing Metal to draw from hundreds to thousands of stamped polygons in a fraction of a second. I know Metal is quite capable, but I'm trying to think of a smart way to build this so I can keep a high degree of interactivity.